# Class não encontrada no servidor remoto

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho o seguinte arquivo **index.php**

```
<?php

  require_once 'global/erros/erros.ini';   
  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';  

  use CLASSES\INIT\Init; 

  new Init();

?>
```

E a seguinte **classe** `Init.php`

```
<?php

  namespace CLASSES\INIT;

  use CLASSES\CONFIG\Config;

  class Init extends Config {   

    protected function iniciaRotas() {

        $ar["home"]     = array("rota"=>"/crud/", "controle"=>"site", "acao"=>"index");
        $ar["index"]    = array("rota"=>"/crud/index", "controle"=>"site", "acao"=>"index");
        $ar["admin"]    = array("rota"=>"/crud/admin", "controle"=>"admin", "acao"=>"index");

        $this->configRotas($ar);

   }

  }
?>
```

E o seguinte `autoload_ps4`

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'CLASSES\\' => array($baseDir . '/classes'),
);
```

Então, localmente (localhost) funciona.

Mas quando subo para o servidor dá erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CLASSES\INIT\Init' not found in 
/var/www/html/funerariasaopedro.net.br/web/crud/index.php on line 8
```

Não faz muito sentido!

Árvore

```
\
\index.php
\classes\
\classes\init\
\classes\init\Init.php
```

Como eu parei no `composer.json` para gerar o `autoload_psr4.php`?

Desta forma:

```
'CLASSES\\UTIL\\'  : '/classes/util',
'CLASSES\\MVC\\CONTROLES\\'  : '/classes/mvc/controles'
```

Ou dessa?

```
'CLASSES\\UTIL\\Util\\'  : '/classes/util/Util.php',
'CLASSES\\MVC\\CONTROLES\\Administradores\\'  : '/classes/mvc/controles/Administradores.php',
'CLASSES\\MVC\\CONTROLES\\Base\\'  : '/classes/mvc/controles/Base.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

Localmente deve estar a funcionar porque o Windows, normalmente, é case-insensitive.

No servidor, que deve ser baseado em linux, será case-sensitive.

Podes mudar o `vendor/autoload.php` para converter o caminho sempre para lowercase, se, for sempre essa a tua regra, ou então mudar no `use CLASSES\INIT\Init;` para representar o que está no filesystem, mas ai provavelmente vais ter de mudar em vários ficheiros.

Tem também atenção que o `autoload.php` que estás a usar foi gerado pelo `composer` alterar esse ficheiro pode ter outras consequências.

Comment: pois é. Mas como podes ver na pegunta, os caminhos e os nomes dos arquivos estão corretamente definidos respeitando case-sensitive regra!

Comment: Não sei, tenho quase a certeza que é esse o problema, porque o erro diz `Fatal error: Class 'CLASSES\INIT\Init' not found in` mostrando que está a tentar aceder a uma pasta `CLASSES\INIT`, tal como tens no `uses`, e na lista de pastas que mostras no exemplo `Árvore` eles estão com lowercase. O código também não indica haver outro problema, até porque funciona no teu local, e assumo que todos os ficheiros estejam no servidor.

Comment: CLASSES\INIT\Init não é pasta. É namespace!

Comment: Certo! Mas o autoload usa isso pra saber onde ir buscar o ficheiro que indicas ai

Comment: Os namespaces tem que ser exatamente os nomes das pastas? É isso? Se for, realmente está errado. Mas peguei exemplo na internet

Comment: Não tem mesmo de ser o caminho tal como está no filesystem, mas por norma é. A função de `autoload` é que usa o caminho especificado no `uses` para perceber onde ir procurar o ficheiro indicado e automaticamente o carregar, sem teres de usar `include` ou `require`, ele faz isso por ti.

Comment: adicionei dados ao final da pergunta. dá uma olhada fazendo favor?